# field accepts everything! How to restrict the data types accepted by the field?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a bug my student ID field accepts  everything, including strings, it should accept only integers how can I fix this bug, so I dont really know how to restrict the data type that is accepted by the field student ID. Is there an API or sth that could be used?

This is HTML CODE:

```html
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
          <form>
            <h1>
              Waiting list for classes
            </h1>
            <body>
              <br>
              <form>
                First Name 
                <input type="text" name="first ">
                <br>
                <br>
                Last Name 
                <input type="text" name="last ">
                <br>
                <br>
                Student ID number 
                <input type="text" name="last ">
                <br>
                <br>
                E-mail: 
                <input type="email" name="email">
                <br>
                <br>
              </br>
              Phone number: 
              <input type="text" name="Phone">
              <br>
              <br>
              Which course's waiting list would you like to join? 
              <select>
                <option value="Visa">
                  CSE 430
                </option>
                <option value="American express">
                  CSE 328
                </option>
                <option value="Discover">
                  CSE 456
                </option>
                <option value="MasterCard">
                  CSE 786
                </option>
                <option value="American express">
                  CSE 987
                </option>
                <option value="Discover">
                  CSE 775
                </option>
                <option value="MasterCard">
                  CSE 342
                </option>
                <option value="American express">
                  CSE 222
                </option>
                <option value="Discover">
                  CSE 134
                </option>
                <option value="MasterCard">
                  CSE 364
                </option>
              </select>
              <br>
            </br>
            Have you ever been on a course's waiting list?
            <br>
          </br>
          <input type="radio" name="Phone" value="no" id="phone_no"/>
          YES
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="Phone" value="yes" id="phone_yes"/>
          NO, this is the first time
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <button onclick="myFunction()">
            Submit Request
          </button>
          <script>
            function myFunction() {
              alert("Thank you very much for your submission, we will process your request!");
            }
          </script>
          <br>
        </br>
        <br>
        </br>
        <!--color 
        <input type="text" name="Color ">
        <br>
        -->
        <!-- chooser 
        <input type="color" name="chooser-inp">
        <br>
        -->
        <!-- Birthday: 
        <input type="date" name="bday">
        <br>
        -->
        <!--Birthday (date and time): 
        <input type="datetime" name="bdaytime">
        <br>
        -->
        <!-- Birthday (date and time): 
        <input type="datetime-local" name="bdaytime">
        <br>
        -->
        <!-- E-mail: 
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <br>
        -->
        <!--    Birthday (month and year): 
        <input type="month" name="bdaymonth">
        <br>
        -->
        <!-- Quantity (between 1 and 5): 
        <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
        <br>
        -->
        <!--Points:
        <input type="range" name="points" min="1" max="10">
        10
        <br>
        -->
        <!--Search Google: 
        <input type="search" name="googlesearch">
        <br>
        -->
        <!--    Select a time: 
        <input type="time" name="usr_time">
        <br>
        -->
        <!-- Add your homepage: 
        <input type="url" name="homepage">
        <br>
        -->
        <br>
        </br>
        <br>
        </br>
        
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
        </body>
        </html>
        <br>
        </br>
        
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
Student Id : <input type="text" id="student_id" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#student_id").keypress(function (e) {         
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)){                      
               return false;
    }
   });
```

This code will allow only integer number in `student_id` field.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/5112/)**

Answer (score 0):

To only accept a number, you can use some new features that come with HTML5.

```
<input type="number" step="1">
```

Or

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d+">
```

Or you can use jQuery, as stated in other answer. But keep in mind that none of these ways is foolproof. A client can always modify HTML/JavaScript in *Developer Tools*. So, you still need to validate the data on the server.